# Testing TextInput Component in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have some problems with testing `TextInput` changes in **react-native** with **jest** and **enzyme**.

My component that handles user input basically looks like this (simplified):

```
class Search extends React.PureComponent {
  onSearchTextChange = input => {
    // do something awesome
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={debounce(this.onSearchTextChange, 800)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to test the text input behaviour. This is what the test looks like right now:

```
it('should render a text input and react to user input', done => {
  const mockOnSearchTextChange = jest.fn();
  Search.prototype.onSearchTextChange = mockOnSearchTextChange;

  const tree = shallow(<Search />);
  const textInput = tree.find('TextInput');
  expect(textInput).toHaveLength(1);
  textInput.simulate('changeText', { target: { value: 'test' } });
  expect(mockOnSearchTextChange).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(mockOnSearchTextChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
    done();
  }, 1500);
});
```

When running this test, I get this error message

> Expected mock function to have been called with:
>   ["test"]
>
> But it was not called.

So the mocked function is never called as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this using [`react-native-testing-library`](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library).

```
// ...
import { render, act, fireEvent } from 'react-native-testing-library'
// ...
it ('does stuff', () => {
  const mock = jest.fn()
  const component = render(<Search onSearchTextChange={mock}/>)
  fireEvent.changeText(component.findByType(TextInput), 'test')
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test')
})
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to add another library. Jest and Enzyme can perform the required testing. Below is the definition of SearchBar component which receives a function as a prop. The function is called with the text typed.

```
const SearchBar = ({onSearch}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => onSearch(text)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

The testing can be carried as follows

```
    const onSearch = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<SearchBar onSearch={onSearch} />);
    wrapper.find('TextInput').simulate('changeText', 'test search text');
    expect(onSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test search text');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add and testID in your TextInput Field and accessibilityLabel as one of the props,
add both for ios and android compatibility,
Here is the TextInput code.

```
   <TextInput
         placeholder='Email Address'
         testID='#email'
         accessibilityLabel='#email'
         blurOnSubmit={ false }
         onEndEditing={this.onSubmitLogin}
         >
         </TextInput>
```

In your test file do a shallow rendering, here

```
    describe('Your component', () => {
     it('Component: renders correctly', () => {
     const tree = renderer.create(<YourComponent/>).toJSON();
     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  it('Has  TextInput', () => {
   const tree2 = renderer.create(<YourComponent/>).toJSON();
   expect(findElement(tree2, '#email')).toBeDefined();
 });

});
```

Then define the function findElement above describe.
With console.warn you should see your props of TextInput and in that your testID

```
   const findElement = function (tree2, element) {
   let result = undefined
   console.warn(tree2.children)
   for(node in tree2.children){
   if(tree2.children[node].props.testID = element) {
   result = true
   }
  }
   return result
 }
```

It will test for all available TextInputs 
....
Note: Shallow rendering will only work if the TextInput is only one level deep(Inside one view only) if it is nested refer here - https://medium.com/@AidThompsin/heres-how-you-unit-test-textinput-with-react-native-63e1f7692b17