# How to test the value of TextInput in react-native

Tags: react-native

I followed the chosen answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750611/testing-textinput-component-in-react-native) thread, but I couldn't figure it out. I want to test the value of a `TextInput` component so I could check the length of it, what is the proper way to achieve this today? 
My component looks something like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default function TextInputComponent(props) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        props.text ? setText(props.text) : setText('');
    }, []);

    const handleInputTextChange = text => {
        setText(text);
    };

    return (
        <TextInput
            onChangeText={text => handleInputTextChange(text)}
            value={text}
            maxLength={maxLength}
            testID="text-input"
        />

    );
}
```

And the test file I constructed so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {render} from 'react-native-testing-library';
import TextInputComponent from 'components/textInputComponent/textInputComponent';

describe('<TextInputComponent />', () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        renderer.create(<TextInputComponent />);
    });

    it('should show "AAA" with text="AAAA" and maxLength="3" props', () => {
        const props = {
            text: 'AAAA',
            maxLength: 3,
        };

        const {queryByTestId} = render(<TextInputComponent {...props} />);

        const textInput = queryByTestId('text-input');

        console.log(textInput);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is to limit the initial text passed in props to the maxLength of characters passed.

in your component `useEffect()` ,

instead of:

```
props.text ? setText(props.text) : setText('');
```

slice the initial text:

```
props.text ? setText(props.text.slice(0, maxLength)) : setText('');
```

that should work for having the text length less than the maxLength too.