# react native Unable to find an element with the testID

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm getting this error:

> `Unable to find an element with the testID of: input-text`

**Input.js**:

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Text, TextInput } from "react-native-paper";

const Input = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        name={props.name}
        keyboardType={props.keyboardType}
        value={props.value}
        label={props.label}
        mode="outlined"
        onChange={(newVal) => props.onChange(props.name, newVal)}
        required={props.required}
        data-testid="input-text"
      />
      <Text>{props.errors}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

**Input-test.js**:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Input } from "../components/common";

import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react-native";

import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

const setup = () => {
  const utils = render(<Input />);
  const input = utils.getByTestId("input-text");
  return {
    input,
    ...utils,
  };
};

test("It should display empty value", () => {
  const { input } = setup();
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "" } });
  expect(input.value).toBe("");
});
```

The reason I'm using `getByTestId` is because the input name is dynamic,
it is rendered multiple times with using forms,
therefore I cannot use anything else.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing TextInput Component in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750611/testing-textinput-component-in-react-native)

Comment: Why wouldn't it work with testing-library tho?

Answer (score 8):

I got caught on the same thing. As explained by the error message, testing library is looking for a prop called `testID`, not `data-testid` as mentioned in the core documentation. Try changing the prop to `testID="input-text"` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, sir, way too used to react web

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, according to [this](https://medium.com/@AidThompsin/heres-how-you-unit-test-textinput-with-react-native-63e1f7692b17) guide, to test `onChange` event in `TextInput` you have to:

1. Install `react-test-renderer`:

   ```
   npm i react-test-renderer
   ```
2. Modify input component like this:

   ```
    const Input = (props) => {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
          myVal: ''
      };
    }

    handleNewVal = (newVal) => {
       this.setState({myVal: newVal});
    }

     return (
     <View>
       <TextInput
         name={props.name}
         keyboardType={props.keyboardType}
         value={props.value}
         label={props.label}
         mode="outlined"
         onChange={(newVal) => this.handleNewVal(newVal)}
         required={props.required}
         data-testid="input-text"
       />
       <Text>{props.errors}</Text>
    </View>
   );
   };
   ```
3. Modify your test in this way:

   ```
   import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

   test("It should display empty value", () => {
     const instanceOf = renderer.create(<Input />).getInstance();
     instanceOf.handleNewVal('');
     expect(instanceOf.state.myVal).toEqual('');
   });
   ```

Comment: Is it not possible with testing-library? I've read about using user-event package that can fix the problem but I still get the same error

Comment: Ciao, the problem is that TextInput object is a nested object and it's not so easy get what you want to get simply by using getByTestId("input-text"). That's the reason why I use react-test-renderer

Comment: @Alon it's possible with testing-library, see my answer. It has nothing to do with nesting.

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't individually test out methods, rather, you should test it's side effects because that's just a bit closer to the user experience.